# logmein is constantly trying to launch something on my Mac

Tags: macos, logmein

logmein is constantly trying to launch something on my Mac. I have looked everywhere but I can't find what is kicking it off.

I can't catch it either since it's only there for split second.

```
9/30/14 5:15:57.792 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver[2983]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/: 14A361c: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][238D58F9-901A-3047-9B11-EAC2A66E131C]: 0x2
9/30/14 5:15:57.792 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
9/30/14 5:15:58.798 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver[2984]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/: 14A361c: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][238D58F9-901A-3047-9B11-EAC2A66E131C]: 0x2
9/30/14 5:15:58.798 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
9/30/14 5:15:59.801 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver[2985]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/: 14A361c: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][238D58F9-901A-3047-9B11-EAC2A66E131C]: 0x2
9/30/14 5:15:59.801 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
9/30/14 5:16:00.858 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver[2986]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/: 14A361c: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][238D58F9-901A-3047-9B11-EAC2A66E131C]: 0x2
9/30/14 5:16:00.858 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
9/30/14 5:16:01.866 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver[2987]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/: 14A361c: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][238D58F9-901A-3047-9B11-EAC2A66E131C]: 0x2
9/30/14 5:16:01.866 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.logmein.logmeinserver) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
```

Comment: On Windows, LogMeIn installs 3 services when installed. I'm assuming it installs at least one service/daemon on a Mac. So that begs the question, did you install LogMeIn on the machine in question?

Comment: I installed the "alpha" of Ignition for Mac at one point, but it had expired since and there is no uninstall besides deleting the app.

Comment: I just upgraded to GM of Yosemite and that seems to have resolved the issue for now. I ran multiple scans over the file structure and looked at all launcher areas and could not find anything mentioning logmein anymore.

Comment: I've had the same but opposite -- post upgrade I have this happening. I logged into OS X's console and found this streaming constantly: 

`(com.logmein.logmeinguiagent[78932]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error=2, path=/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/LogMeIn.app/Contents/Resources/LMIGUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS: 14A388b: xpcproxy + 12907 [1227][1016C726-9ACF-3A24-9C51-A279F5C6B167]: 0x2`

I don't have LogMeIn installed in any capacity that I can uninstall, so any ideas on how to clear this one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You just need to execute in console the following command:

```
sudo launchctl remove com.logmein.logmeinserver
```